# How to substitute part of an expression in vim using substitute

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

How do I put a part of search pattern in substitution string.

I have to replace `abc->hwqe_w1_len` with `common_wqe_get_len(abc)`
Similarly this one `def->hwqe_w1_len` with `common_wqe_get_len(def)`

using only one expression in vim substitute command.

I tried using the following command but it says invalid command.
`:%s /\(.*\)->hwqe_w1_len/\='common_wqe_get_len(' . submatch(1) '\)'/gc`

When I remove the closing brace it works, but it takes the spaces before `abc`
`:%s /\(.*\)->hwqe_w1_len/\='common_wqe_get_len(' . submatch(1)/gc`

What is the mistake I am doing? How do I put `abc` with out spaces and the closing brace at the end?

Comment: You're missing the concatenation operator `.` after `submatch(1)`. But as this is all textual, you don't need a replace-expression, a simple `\1` backreference will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/\(\w*\)->hwqe_w1_len/common_wqe_get_len(\1)/g
```